# Taking to much time to update the fields of my firebase project

Tags: angular, firebase

well, let me try to explain that.
In my project i have a page where i am supposed to update a value of a collection in my firebase project. So, my code do it correct in a first button click in template, but on a second click, it update again and keeps update the fields in the firebase's collection till the page clashes or take to much time to update it.

````
<div class="card mt-5 pt-5" *ngFor="let p of pizzas | async">
  <p class="card-title">{{p.nome}}</p>
  <p>{{p.id}}</p>
  ```<button (click)="UpdateProducts(p.id)">Update</button>
 </div>

</div>
//Object Pizza: 
  {
   nome: "", 
   ingredients: ["tomato sauce", "Mozzarela", ...],
   quantity: ["300", "400",...]
  }
  

  > Objective of the code: Since i use a certain quantity of each ingredient in a pizza i can update each product in the database mapping the ingredient array with the quantity array.
ex: stock of mozzarela in the DB has 4000g, if i map ingredient[1] and quantity[1] i will have product Mozzarela: [4000 - 400] in the DB. Which means that Product Mozzarela equal to 3600g. 

export class TestePizzaComponent implements OnInit {
pizzas: any = ""
id: string = ""

quantity: Array<any> = []
prod: any
constructor(private afire: AngularFirestore, 
  private serv: ProductService,
  private route: Router) { }


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.pizzas = this.afire.collection<any>("pizza").snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(changes => changes.map(a => {
        var id = a.payload.doc.id
        var data = a.payload.doc.data()
        return { id, ...data }
      }))
    )

}
atualizar(id: string) {

var quantArry = []
var ing = []
var quant = [] 
this.afire.doc<any>('pizza/' + id).valueChanges()
.pipe(
  map(value => {
    ing = value.ingredientes.split(",")
    quant = value.quantidade.split(",")
    for (let q of quant) {
      quantArry.push(q);
    }
      return { ing, quantArry }
  })
).subscribe(
   value => {
    for (let val of value.ing) {
      this.afire.collection('products', ref => ref.where('nomeProduto', 
'==', val))
        .valueChanges().subscribe(
           v => {
            this.prod = v[0]
            this.prod.quantidadeEstoque = quant[ing.indexOf(val)]
             this.serv.update(this.prod, this.prod.id)
            //this.prod = null
          })```
````

Comment: You will need to post some code, but it sounds like an infinite loop.

Comment: Nothing was posted.  You should update your original question, not add it as a comment.

Comment: Ok, posted. think got it right.

Comment: what does this code method do `UpdateProducts(p.id)` and also from `atualizar(id: string) { ...} ` method you have `this.serv.update(this.prod, this.prod.id)`

Comment: well, atuaizar(id) will get the pizzas' information using the id of the record in the firebase. So i will use the fields ingredients="mozzarela, sauce,.." and quantity="400, 120,.." to update each product in the database. Ex.: mozzarela in the database is 4000, so i will get the product Mozzarela in ingredientes, get the 1° value in quantity and subtract from 4000.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following all the logic, a combination of it being in Italian(?) and not the greatest formatting.

The main problem is on your click event you call `atualizar()`, and that creates a `valueChanges` subscription to a pizza object (?) which you never unsubscribe from, where you are doing something with the data, then after that you create a valueChange subscription to a collection (which you also never unsubscribe from) that filters products, inside that you are eventually calling `this.serv.update(this.prod, this.prod.id)`

I'm guessing `this.serv.update(this.prod, this.prod.id)` is making changes to the pizza object or the collection of products, and since you never unsubscribe to valueChanges they are getting called over and over, and every time you click and run `atualizar()` again you are adding another endless loop of subscriptions.

I don't really have time to fix all of your code (and it would be hard to do it anyway without having your exact firebase setup), but the above description and these tips I hope help point you in the right direction:

1. Using `valueChanges` in firebase doesn't just get the object, it gets the object and keeps an open subscription for every time it changes.  You can use`take(1)` rxjs pipe/operator to manage the subscription properly.
2. Since you are getting multiple objects from the server in separate calls, you probably want to use rxjs `switchMap` to help manage the subscription.  In your case it looks like you are firing off multiple other requests in a for loop so it might not be appropriate in this case and would likely need some sort of Combination operator (I'm not sure which one is appropriate, for your use case, but they are all listed here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination).

Here's an example of using `take(1)` to end the subscription to the pizza document:

```
this.afire.doc<any>('pizza/' + id).valueChanges()
.pipe(
   map(values => {
    // some stuff..
    return { ing, quantArry }
   }),
   take(1)
).subscribe(val)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I reach a resolution using the TAKE operator and it worked as desired but the SWITCHMAP thing couldn't make this out. Obs: I set the TAKE operator in the second valueschanges() since i'm trying update the product object.